# Range Attribute in MVC 5 not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, range, unobtrusive-validation

I am learning MVC (version 5) by doing a sample project. Hence I am not using any scaffolding and doing everything from scratch. I have a View Model, which has a Password field with the following validations.

```
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is Required.")]
    [Range(1, 4, ErrorMessage = "{0} has to be between {1} and {2} characters.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Now in my .cshtml, I have a password textbox rendered using @Html.EditorFor. Since I am learning, I don't have any css added. I have added references to jquery-1.10.2.js, jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js in the cshtml file. The validations are working properly, except for the above password field. If I enter only 1 character in the password textbox, validation passes, whereas anything more than that fails, which is strange. I am not able to understand this. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: When you put 2 characters it exceed the range i.e.12 which is greater than 4, but what you inter pretending as length. please see the answer for details

Comment: As stated already, `range` is for numbers, not length of strings.  Also, the question is really about how to properly use the Unobtrusive Validation plugin as part of ASP, not the underlying jQuery Validate.  Edited tags.

Comment: Thanks Sparky. Your comment answers the question better. Please add your comment as Reply and I will mark it as Reply.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using this as string please use below method

```
[StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "{0} has to be between {1} and {2} characters.")]
```

What you have done is specified value in range so when you put **1 to 4** in the field its valid if you put **5** its not valid because it exceeds the range.

When you need length not the actual value you should use **string length** on property.

Hope this will solve the problem